# Parameters.Add ignoring position of parameter in string

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, ms-access

I'm trying to make an INSERT command with some parameters, like login, password, first name and last name, but using Parameters.Add in a "random" order doesn't seem to place the parameters where they need to be.

Here's what I've tried:
I create a base string with the parameters and in order to add each parameter, I loop through all the controls named "field*" in the form, add their Tag (like "login") as parameter and its .Text property as value. The code is the following:

```
commandString = "INSERT INTO users (login, password, name, last_name, area, cargo, level) values (@login, @password, @name, @last_name, @area, @cargo, @level)"

command = New OleDbCommand()
command.connection = connection

For Each field In Me.Controls
     If field.name Like "field*" Then
          command.Parameters.Add("@" & field.Tag, OleDbType.Variant)
          command.Parameters("@" & field.Tag).Value = field.Text
     End If
Next

command.commandText = commandString
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

E.g. the textbox named "fieldLogin" has the .Tag "login".

The order of the controls in the form.Controls collection is pretty much "random"

When the program executes the command, the values appear in the order the control "appeared" in the loop, not in the right position in the command string. For example, if the password field appears before login, the command inserts into the database something like login = '12345', password = 'user1'.

How can I make the command insert the values in the correct argument positions?

I'm using an Access database.

Comment: Access doesn't support named parameters.  You can use names but they are ignored.  You MUST add parameters to the command in the same order as they appear in the SQL code.

Comment: VB`Adodb.Parameters`are not named. They appear in creation order.  You can only adjust the`commandString`having the fields inserted as they appear, but by using`OleDbType.Variant`you lose type-safety of the parameters. Just add them explicit each and provide proper type check. All in one loop is too lazy.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher `All in one loop is too lazy`, can you explain what is meant?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ bad idea saving 8 lines of code (7 inserted values, each needs 2 lines for the parameter, the loop and the if consume 4 additional).

Comment: Also, the reserved names must be bracketed: `"INSERT INTO users (login, [password], [name], last_name, area, cargo, level) VALUES (@login, @password, @name, @last_name, @area, @cargo, @level)"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try building up the field list and parameter list together in the loop.. something like this off the top of my head:

```
Dim commandString As String = "INSERT INTO users ({fields}) VALUES ({values})"
Dim commandFields As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
Dim commandValues As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

For Each control As Control In Controls
    If control.Name.StartsWith("field") Then
        commandFields.Add(control.Tag)
        commandValues.Add($"@{control.Tag}")

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@{control.Tag}", control.Text)
    End If
Next

commandString = commandString.Replace("{fields}", String.Join(", ", commandFields)
commandString = commandString.Replace("{values}", String.Join(", ", commandValues)
```

Comment: With Option Strict On the Object returned by `control.Tag` cannot be converted to the String needed to `.Add` to `commandFields`. Just need to add a .ToString()